# subsetting quickly over many columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some code that identifies outliers in a data frame and then either removes or caps them. I'm trying to speed up the removal process using an apply() function (or perhaps another method).

**Example data**

```
https://github.com/crossfitAL/so_ex_data/blob/master/subset
# this is the contents of a csv file, you will need to load it into your R session.

# set up an example decision-matrix
# rm.mat is a {length(cols) x 4} matrix -- in this example 8 x 4
# rm.mat[,1:2] - identify the values for min/max outliers, respectively.
# rm.mat[,3:4] - identify if you wish to remove min/max outliers, respectively.
cols <- c(1, 6:12) # specify the columns you wish to examine
rm.mat <- matrix(nrow = length(cols), ncol= 4, 
                dimnames= list(names(fico2[cols]), 
                c("out.min", "out.max","rm outliers?", "rm outliers?")))

# add example decision criteria
rm.mat[, 1] <- apply(fico2[, cols], 2, quantile, probs= .05)
rm.mat[, 2] <- apply(fico2[, cols], 2, quantile, probs= .95)
rm.mat[, 3] <- replicate(4, c(0,1))
rm.mat[, 4] <- replicate(4, c(1,0))
```

**Here's my current code for subsetting:**

```
df2 <- fico2 # create a copy of the data frame
cnt <- 1     # add a count variable
for (i in cols) { 
# for each column of interest in the data frame. Determine if there are min/max 
# outliers  that you wish to remove, remove them.        
  if (rm.mat[cnt, 3] == 1 & rm.mat[cnt, 4] == 1) {
    # subset / remove min and max outliers
    df2 <- df2[df2[, i] >= rm.mat[cnt, 1] & df2[, i] <= rm.mat[cnt, 2], ]  
  } else if (rm.mat[cnt, 3] == 1 & rm.mat[cnt, 4] == 0) {
    # subset / remove min outliers
    df2 <- df2[df2[, i] >= rm.mat[cnt, 1], ]
  } else if (rm.mat[cnt, 3] == 0 & rm.mat[cnt, 4] == 1) {
    # subset / remove max outliers
    df2 <- df2[df2[, i] <= rm.mat[cnt, 2], ]
  }
  cnt <- cnt + 1
}
```

**proposed solution**:
I think I should be able to do this via an apply type function, with the removal of the for loop / vectorization speeding up the code. The problem that I'm running into is that I'm trying to apply a function *if-and-only-if* the the decision-matrix indicates that I should. IE- using a logical vector `rm.mat[,3] or rm.mat[,4]` to determine if subsetting `"["` should be applied to the dataframe `df2`.

Any help you have would be greatly appreciated! Also, please let me know if the example data / code is sufficient.

Comment: Hi Alex, Just a suggestion: I think it would be more helpful if your instead of posting how you're cleaning the data you would instead just post a sample of your data (or a stripped down sim.).

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - not my actual data. It's some example data from a Coursera class. My data is large and high-dim. I thought this would be simpler.

Comment: @Alex, I second RicardoSaporta's suggestion that it would be better if you reframe your problem by **focussing only** on it without too much introduction. I am trying to read the 3rd time! There are no comments in your code. You expect people to look at the code and understand... I don't think many people will attempt to answer.

Comment: @Alex your rm.mat is not good! it is a matrix 6*2 , so rm.mat[, 3] leads to an error! what do you try to do ? and have all this condition for a small matrix (maybe you try to simplify the example, but here your sample don't work)

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I'll re-write the entry per the comments

Comment: updated, let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: I guess we have to load the file into `fico2`? your `rm.mat` commands give error (as agstudy already mentioned).

Comment: The problem I think is with `cols=6`. It points to `home.ownership` which is not a `numeric` to take `quantiles`.

Comment: @Arun - I don't believe so, although I apologize that you're having trouble while trying to be helpful. `names(fico2)[6] = "monthly.income"` and the `rm.mat` code is running properly for me. Are you sure you grabbed the rm.mat code after my edits?

Comment: These are my first 7 columns: `X, amount.funded.by.investors,  loan.length, loan.purpose, state, home.ownership, monthly.income` (and the CSV you linked has 13 columns). I'll take `c(1, 7:13)` instead.

Comment: Also, your first `if-statement`: `rm.mat[cnt, 3] == 1 & rm.mat[cnt, 4] == 1` is never `TRUE` as you have made sure they are always `1,0` or `0,1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution. just to clarify your code. Hope that others can use it to give a better solution.

So if understand, you have a decision matrix, that looks like this :

```
rm.mat
                                      c1 c2 c3 c4
amount.funded.by.investors     27925.000 NA  0  1
monthly.income                 11666.670 NA  1  0
open.credit.lines                 18.000 NA  0  1
revolving.credit.balance       40788.750 NA  1  0
inquiries.in.the.last.6.months     3.000 NA  0  1
debt.to.inc                       28.299 NA  1  0
int.rate                          20.490 NA  0  1
fico.num                         775.000 NA  1  0
```

And you try to filter a big matrix according to the values of this matrix

```
colnames(rm.mat) <- paste('c',1:4,sep='')    
rm.mat <- as.data.frame(rm.mat)
apply(rm.mat,1,function(y){
     h <- paste(y['c3'],y['c4'],sep='')
     switch(h,
            '11'= apply(df2,2, function(x)
                               df2[x >= y['c1'] &  x <= y['c2'],]),  ## we never have this!!
            '10'= apply(df2,2, function(x)
                               df2[x >= y['c1'] , ]),   ## here we apply by columns!
            '01'= apply(df2,2,function(x) 
                               df2[x <= y['c2'], ]))   ## c2 is NA!! so !!!
 }
)
```

Comment: your `rm.mat` is not what I have. `rm.mat[, 1] <- apply(fico2[, cols], 2, quantile, probs= .05)
rm.mat[, 2] <- apply(fico2[, cols], 2, quantile, probs= .95)`. I think your solution may work... I'm going to have to come back to it tonight though. I'm unfamiliar with using `switch()`. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex my solution is really to show you that before thinking performance , you MUST write CLEAN and READABLE code! Once you have this you can tune it! taht's said switch is really a handy function when you have many conditions..

Comment: I agree with you. A) I'm still improving my R coding; but B) I think this has more to do with trying to provide a short and relatively simple example from 1 piece of a function that has 200 lines of code... that said, I do REALLY appreciate you, and the others on this post, taking the time to work through this despite being frustrated.

Comment: Function that has **200** lines of code!! at least 200 lines sources of bug :) good luck to maintain this!